# How to get the search result from BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am not super used to Beautifulsoup yet (even though it is super useful). My question that I have is if I have a website like this

https://bigd.big.ac.cn/dogsdv2/pages/modules/indsnp/indsnp_search.jsp

and I were to get results from passing in P2RY12 into "gene name" input box, what do I need to do?

Also, in general, if I want to get a search result from a certain website what do I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

If you open Firefox/Chrome webmaster tools, you can observe where the page is making requests. So when typing `P2RY12` into search box and clicking the submit button, the page is making POST request to `http://bigd.big.ac.cn/dogsdv2/indsnp/searchIndSNPSingle.action`.

In general, you need to know the URL and parameters sent to the URL to get any information back.

This example grabs some information from the first page of results:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://bigd.big.ac.cn/dogsdv2/indsnp/searchIndSNPSingle.action'

data = {
    'totalCount': -1,
    'searchForm.chrom': 0,
    'searchForm.start': '',
    'searchForm.end': '',
    'searchForm.rsid': '',
    'searchForm.popu':  0,
    'searchForm.geneid': '',
    'searchForm.genename': 'P2RY12',
    'searchForm.goterm': '',
    'searchForm.gokeyword': '',
    'searchForm.limitFlag': 1,
    'searchForm.numlimit':  1000
}

headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://bigd.big.ac.cn/dogsdv2/pages/modules/indsnp/indsnp_search.jsp',
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')

for td in soup.select('table.table7 tr > td:nth-child(3)'):
    a = td.select_one('a')
    print('SNP ID:', a.get_text(strip=True))
    t1 = a.find_next_sibling('br').find_next_sibling(text=True)
    print('Position:', t1.strip())
    print('Location:', ', '.join( l.get_text(strip=True) for l in t1.find_next_siblings('a') ))
    print('Genotype:', a.find_next_siblings('br')[2].find_next_sibling(text=True).strip())
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
SNP ID: cfa19627795
Position: Chr23:45904511
Location: ENSCAFG00000008485, ENSCAFG00000008531, ENSCAFG00000008534
Genotype: G
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SNP ID: cfa19627797
Position: Chr23:45904579
Location: ENSCAFG00000008485, ENSCAFG00000008531, ENSCAFG00000008534
Genotype: C
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SNP ID: cfa19627803
Position: Chr23:45904842
Location: ENSCAFG00000008485, ENSCAFG00000008531, ENSCAFG00000008534
Genotype: C
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, but one more question. From your code ```for td in soup.select('table.table7 tr > td:nth-child(3)'):``` what does that do?? and what does that mean?

Comment: @Young the `.select()` method accepts CSS selector. So `'table.table7 tr > td:nth-child(3)'` means to select every 3rd tag `<td>` directly under every `<tr>` tag under `<table class="table7">` More about CSS selector here: https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/

Comment: Hi I got a following question. I was able to get the search result from the code you provided. However, the part that I am actually trying to get data from is from the link that is in href. The problem raises here. So, if I try to get to that href path directly from a browser, or request.urlopen it shows me some other site. What can I do to bypass this?

Comment: @Young You can try to set `User-Agent` header, and/or open the link under the session (https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) - that will keep track of the cookies. Or use `http` instead of `https`. There are many possibilities, every server behaves a little bit different.

Comment: @ Andrej Kesely I have another follow up question. I am currently working on webscrapping from other website but how do I identify header variable and csrf cookie?